# Copy List Item to a new item in the same list with workflow designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, designer-workflow, copy-item

I have a SharePoint list item with all of the fields filled in, and want to simply copy that item to create a new one. I want to create a button on a list item which will “copy to new” and then automatically bring up the new item to edit.

Is that possible with SharePoint and SharePoint Designer 2007 and how do I do this? I am new to SharePoint and Designer and not very familiar to the SPD GUI. So please keep this in mind when answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Take a look at this following great example explained by Laura Rogers with all the necessary detail: [Click to Copy List Item to New in SharePoint 2007](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=107).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Pradip :) I saw this post too, but I had great problems from step 5 because it is for SPD 2010 and not for SPD 2007 and I don't now where to click :(

Comment: This link of video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpbxEnMCWgw) might help you in moving ahead.

Comment: The video helped, thank you :) I will try to move on with Laura's method and will write again if I get stuck.

Comment: Pradip, where can I find the "Form Actions"-window in SPD 2007?

Comment: Any update on this? It's a kind of urgent.

Comment: Refer this link: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Add-a-built-in-form-action-to-a-Data-View-01b541da-b657-402d-95c9-e8dfde6a54bb may be this can help you. There is snap already given in that examples to find the Form action. Make sure you do some research on this.